# Copy contents from one textfield to another with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms, copy

Trying to copy some user input from one HTML `input` to another and my console is showing an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'val'`

Not sure what the issue is.. I thought that a text input *does* have a value? Thanks for your help!

HTML:

```
<input id="a" class="answer" type="text">
<input id="af" type="text" name="a">


$('.answer').bind('keypress', function(){
    var name  = $(this).attr('id'),
        feild = $('#' + name + 'f')[0];

    feild.val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: just remove `[0]` http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/C3YX8/

Comment: i'm an idiot. you should answer so that i can accept it

Comment: accept waitinforatrain's one :-)

Comment: Also change feild to field. o_O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** As @zerkms pointed out, the [0] is not needed anyways, but since it's sometimes useful to use array indices with selectors, I'll leave this here so you understand the error.

Change:

```
field.val($(this).val());
```

to

```
$(field).val($(this).val());
```

Explanation: `$('#' + name + 'f')` gets an array of HTML elements that match the selector. Since you put `[0]` this gets the first HTML element in the array. Since `field` is a HTML element rather than a jQuery object, you need to convert it to a jQuery object using `$(field)` to use jQuery methods on it.

Comment: 1. Get jquery object 2. get DOM object from jquery object 3. convert DOM object back to jquery object. Doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 1):

**First thing** -- a couple of extra points need to be added to really complete the solution here:

- onkeypress events should only be fired for a *character* key press and release (or repeatedly on hold).
- onkeydown/onkeyup events should be fired for any key being pressed/released.

[reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-keyboard-event-order)

Thus you should really be copying the input text on keyup since you want to include deletion actions, paste events, etc..  Even with the @zerkms/@waitinforatrain fix, you will only be able to add info to the second box.

**Second thing** -- this method works, but it doesn't have the snappiness I've seen in actual sites, and I wanted to see if I could get that, so here goes.

Onkeyup/down events don't have character info (or shouldn't), so you can't really use them to help speed up the process.

I fiddled (heh) with it for a while, and what I came up with has a significantly faster response time, although it *does* add a dependency -- [jcaret](http://code.google.com/p/jcaret/downloads/list).

I don't think there are any major bugs, but YMMV.  Also [browser support](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html) for keypress events is ridiculously patchy, but *hopefully* jQuery handles that for you (I only tested this in Chrome).

```
$('.answer').bind('keyup', function(e){
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + 'f').val($(this).val());
});

$('.answer').keypress(function(e){
    var newChar = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
    var oldVal = $(this).val();
    var cursorPos = $(this).caret().start;

    var newVal = oldVal.slice(0, cursorPos) + newChar + oldVal.slice(cursorPos);

    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + 'f').val(newVal);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HuepG/8/)

Hope this helps!
​